# Class.getDeclaredConstructor doesn't retrieve compatible argument supertype constructors

Tags: java, reflection

In my program, I register `JComponent` classes to my classes that handle them for my purposes (converting their values to setting entries). It looks like this:

```
 InputHandlers.register(InputJTextField.class,  javax.swing.JPasswordField.class);
 InputHandlers.register(InputJTextField.class,  JTextField.class);
 InputHandlers.register(InputJCheckBox.class,  JCheckBox.class);
 ...
```

I save these registered values to `Map` and retrieve them later. But for the example above, I have a problem: though `javax.swing.JPasswordField.class` is subtype of `JTextField.class`, the `Class.getDeclaredConstructor` doesn't see it that way.

I made a general example to make this question easier to answer. Consider following classes:

```
  class A {
    private final B b;
    public A(B b) {
      this.b = b;
    }
  }
  class B {}
  class C extends B {}
```

Imagine you want to do this:

```
 A.class.getDeclaredConstructor(C.class);
```

It will throw `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` even though `C` is subtype of `B`. Here's the full code:

```
/**
 * Test how Class.getDeclaredConstructor seeks for constructors.
 * @author Jakub
 */
public class Constructors {
  public static class A {
    private final B b;
    public A(B b) {
      this.b = b;
    }
  }
  public static class B {}
  public static class C extends B {}
  public static void main(String[] args) //throws Exception
  {
    /** TRY USING REFLECTION **/
    //Make A from B
    tryAfromParam(new B());
    //Make A from C that is cast to B
    tryAfromParam((B)new C());
    //Make A from C without casting
    tryAfromParam(new C());
  }
  public static A tryAfromParam(Object param) {
    System.out.println("Try to make A from "+param.getClass()+" using A.class.getConstructor(...)");
    try {
      A a = AfromParam(param);
      System.out.println("    Sucess :)");
      return a;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("    CONSTRUCTOR FAILED: "+ex);
    }
    return null;
  }
  public static A AfromParam(Object param) throws Exception {
    //Fetch the A's class instance
    Class cls = A.class;
    //Define constructor parameters
    Class[] arguments = new Class[] {
      param.getClass()
    };
    //Try to get the constructor
    Constructor<A> c = cls.getConstructor(arguments);
    //Try to instantiate A
    A a = c.newInstance(param);
    //Return result
    return a;
  }
}
```

And the question is: How to find constructor compatible with arguments or any of their super types? Note that `new A(new C())` is valid, so the reflection should work the same way - generally I want to call the constructor the way Java would call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this correctly in one line with `java.beans.Expression:`

```
C c;
A a = (A)new Expression(A.class, "new", new Object[]{c}).getValue();
```

Comment: Sounds like the solution I need. I'll accept this as soon as I test it.

Comment: Sorry i downvoted because it seemed not to work, but i made a mistake ... if you edit your answer i can change my vote back to +.

Comment: @FredericLeitenberger There you go.

Answer (score 2):

That's the way all (or most) reflection actions work. They expect and match only for the declared type. In this case, [`Class#getDeclareConstructor(Class...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-)

> Returns a `Constructor` object that reflects the specified public
>   constructor of the class represented by this Class object. **The
>   `parameterTypes` parameter is an array of `Class` objects that identify
>   the constructor's formal parameter types**, in declared order. If this
>   `Class` object represents an inner class declared in a non-static
>   context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing
>   instance as the first parameter.

You'll need to check yourself if your argument type is a subtype of the declared/formal type.

You can do this in a loop

```
// Adjust for number of parameters
public static <T> Constructor<T> getConstructorDynamically(Class<T> clazz, Class<?> argumentType) {
    while (argumentType != null) {
        try {
            return clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(argumentType);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            argumentType = argumentType.getSuperclass();
        }
    }
    return null;
    // or throw
}
```

I'm sure there are some libraries out there that do it but I cannot find them right now (look into Spring, for example).

You can also iterate over the constructors and find one that matches (this is probably much faster as you don't typically declare that many constructors in a class)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Constructor<T> findConstructor(Class<T> clazz, Class<?>[] argumentTypes) {
    Constructor<T>[] constructors = (Constructor<T>[]) clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
    for (Constructor<T> constructor : constructors) {
        // adapt for var args
        if (constructor.getParameterCount() != argumentTypes.length)
            continue;

        Class<?>[] formalTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
        for (int i = 0; i < formalTypes.length; i++) {
            if (!formalTypes[i].isAssignableFrom(argumentTypes[i]))
                continue;
        }
        return constructor;
    }
    return null; // or throw
}
```

Comment: You can do this correctly in one line via `java.beans.Expression.`

Comment: @EJP I didn't find what you were referring to. I've made a community wiki in case you'd like to add that option.

Comment: But imagine solving that for multiple variables! The loop complexity would grow exponentialy with each parameters. And still, you'd never find `A(Object..)` constructor that is valid for any arguments except none. I really want to cover whatever JVM does when you call a function with non-exact arguments.

Comment: @TomášZato You won't be able to do it with reflection. The API just doesn't support it out of the box. I'd look into the `java.lang.invoke` API. Maybe there's something there.

Comment: @EJP It turns out I was trying it with a non-public constructor in a non-public class. I couldn't find anything about access modifiers anywhere in the Javadoc so I gave up.

Comment: The inner `continue` effectively does nothing as it's the last statement in the for loop. More over it continues just the inner for loop which means that the inner for loop is useless and just always iterates through all the `formalTypes` no matter what which means that the constructors are distinguished just by number of parameters and not by it's type at tall. A `break` should have been used there instead or better - the formal types check should be encapsulated in a separate method and then an early return could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an advanced version of Sotirios' code.

I added a `newInstance` method where you can directly pass the class and args and get the new instance returned. And I added null-checks and proper error-handling + nice error-messages.

And i changed `getDeclaredConstructors()` to `getConstructors()` so we only consider public constructors that we can actually call. This change depends on the requirements and might have to be reverted for some cases.

```
/**
 * Creates a new instance for clazz using it's constructor matching the given args.
 * As opposed to the <code>clazz.getConstructor(...).newInstance(args)</code> method
 * this method considers also constructors with matching super-type parameters
 * (as we know it from normal method or constructor invocations).
 * 
 * @param clazz
 * @param args
 * @return
 * @throws InstantiationException
 * @throws IllegalAccessException
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 * @throws InvocationTargetException
 * @throws NoSuchMethodException
 */
public static <T> T newInstance(Class<? extends T> clazz, Object... args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException
{
    return findConstructor(clazz, args).newInstance(args);
}

/**
 * Adopted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/29312271/1520422
 * 
 * @param clazz
 * @param args
 * @return
 * @throws NoSuchMethodException
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Constructor<T> findConstructor(Class<T> clazz, Object... args) throws NoSuchMethodException
{
    Constructor<T> matchingConstructor = null;
    Constructor<T>[] constructors = (Constructor<T>[]) clazz.getConstructors();
    for (Constructor<T> constructor : constructors)
    {
        if (constructor.getParameterCount() != args.length)
        {
            continue;
        }
        Class<?>[] formalTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
        for (int i = 0; i < formalTypes.length; i++)
        {
            if (!formalTypes[i].isInstance(args[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (matchingConstructor != null) // already found one ... so there is more than one ...
        {
            throw new NoSuchMethodException("Multiple constructors found for: " + printArgs(clazz, args) + " --> " + matchingConstructor + " --> " + constructor);
        }
        matchingConstructor = constructor;
    }
    if (matchingConstructor == null)
    {
        throw new NoSuchMethodException("No constructor found for: " + printArgs(clazz, args));
    }
    return matchingConstructor;
}

private static String printArgs(Class<?> clazz, Object... args)
{
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    msg.append("new ");
    msg.append(clazz.getName());
    msg.append("(");
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            msg.append(", ");
        }
        msg.append(args[i] == null ? "null" : args[i].getClass().getName());
    }
    msg.append(")");
    return msg.toString();
}
```